# How to load next youtube in a PHP array?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, youtube.net-api

I have this php/html code which loads a random youtube video from a php array each time the page is loaded. But I want to have next and previous buttons to load the next and previous videos in the array. Only a single video must be loaded at any time. I have this:

```
<?php $videos = array("0jBRY_Aki9s","1czXvHSjDac","1kbiUiRfnh8","377kKBi6anQ"); 

$rand = array_rand($videos); 
$rand_key = $videos[$rand]; 
$numOfItems = count($videos);

echo "<iframe width='375' height='310' 
src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/$rand_key?&amp;fmt=22&amp;autoplay=1'> </iframe>";?> 

<span onclick="<?php $clip = next($videos); 
echo "<iframe style='float:left;' width='375' height='310' 
src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/$clip?&amp;fmt=22&amp;autoplay=1'>
</iframe>";?> ">next</span>
```

Is there some way to use the php "next" method to do change the current video on the iframe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No! You cannot mix `PHP` with `Javascript` like that, `PHP` is server side while `Javascript` is client side, based on browser.
You have 2 options, you can use `AJAX` to load next video, or use an `anchor` to link to next video:

```
<?php
    $videos = array("0jBRY_Aki9s" , "1czXvHSjDac" , "1kbiUiRfnh8" , "1uTypnaP5X4" , "377kKBi6anQ"); 
    $rand = array_rand($videos);
    $rand_key = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : $rand;

    echo "<iframe width='375' height='310' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/".$videos[$rand_key]."?&amp;fmt=22&amp;autoplay=1'> </iframe>";

    $next = isset($videos[($rand_key+1)]) ? ($rand_key+1) : 0;
    $prev = isset($videos[($rand_key-1)]) ? ($rand_key-1) : count($videos)-1;
?> 

<a href="test.php?id=<?php echo $prev; ?>">prev</a> | <a href="test.php?id=<?php echo $next; ?>">next</a>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work: just loads http://communitychessclub.com/next_video.php?id=1czXvHSjDac I will want NEXT and PREV videos using traditional anchor links. Can you please revise your code?

Comment: The NEXT and PREV vids have to load in the same page. Otherwise what's the sense?

Comment: This code only scrolls forward and backward by 1 or two, then no further. BTW isn't is possible to give the iframe an id and have it refresh just that iframe w/o reloading the whole page? That would be elegant, I think.

Comment: @verlager that code will get all videos starting with a random one!

Comment: But this code dw .. only <a href="test.php?id=<?php echo $prev; ?>">prev</a> works. And it still iterates 2x and no further. Try it! http://communitychessclub.com/test.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16353/discussion-between-mihai-iorga-and-verlager)

Comment: Updated the code, it should work now, I got confused about that prev,. next .. now it works

Comment: you forgot to append the 'test.php'

Comment: OP: "I don't want x, I want it x and y", well considering y is a copy paste of x with a little modification... you could just do that instead of whine about it.
@Mihai, I salute your patience on this one.

Comment: The scrolling works fine now! But the initial random video load doesn't work: check this source: <iframe width='375' height='310' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/?&amp;fmt=22&amp;autoplay=1'> </iframe> (see? there's no youtube id)

Comment: It works for me, maybe you forgot to copy last modifications .. ?

Comment: OMG it works! Thank you for this instructive php coding demonstration and I will learn from it.